# Laravel function not being called when browser tab is reopened with ctrl+shift+t

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

As the title says.
There is server side code that must be run every time someone opens up the page in question.

When I navigate to the page in most ways, the code runs as normal.
However, when I press `ctrl+shift+t` and get the tab reopened that way, it appears to use cached information rather than sending a get request to my server.

Is there some code I can put in the front end that will force the page to actually send a request when the tab is unclosed using the shortcut?

Comment: Try using the `location.replace()` method in you js on `onLoad()`.

Comment: This is browser behavior and has nothing to do with Laravel or PHP. You may be able to get the behavior you want by setting cache headers.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-do-we-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers?rq=1